# How to use incomplete types

Tags: typescript, intellisense, typescript-typings

Without creating a new interface / type, and without making all of the fields on my type definition optional, can I reference a type without including all of it's required fields?

Here's an example of the problem:

```
interface Test {
    one: string;
    two: string;
}
_.findWhere<Test, Test>(TestCollection, {
    one: 'name'
});
```

For reference, the type definition for Underscore's `.findWhere` method is this:

```
findWhere<T, U extends {}>(
        list: _.List<T>,
        properties: U): T;
```

I would like to use `T` as the type for the properties parameter since it has the type information I want already, but trying to do this results in this typescript error:

> Argument of type `'{ one: string; }'` is not assignable to parameter of
>   type `'Test'`.   Property `'two'` is missing in type `'{ one: string; }'`.

Is there some extra syntax that will allow me to effectively make the `one` and `two` fields optional as needed? Something like the following:

```
_.findWhere<Test, Test?>(TestCollection, {
    one: 'name'
});
```

I want autocomplete and for it to alert me when I'm using the wrong type information (e.x. strings when number is provided).

Does this exist in the language? Do I have to create a new type just in this case? Am I required to make all my fields optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the thread, Ryan Cavanaugh shared, the latest is that this feature has been added and will be released in a future version in the near future (`2.2.x`?).

From [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4889#issuecomment-261365594) it will look like this:

```
// Example from initial report
interface Foo {
    simpleMember: number;
    optionalMember?: string;
    objectMember: X; // Where X is a inline object type, interface, or other object-like type 
}

// This:
var foo: Partial<Foo>;
// Is equivalent to:
var foo: {simpleMember?: number, optionalMember?: string, objectMember?: X};

// Partial<T> in that PR is defined as this:
// Make all properties in T optional
interface Partial<T> {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
}
```

So, you make a type an incomplete type by making `MyType` into `Partial<MyType>`.

Answer (score 1):

This feature does not yet exist in TypeScript. [This is the suggestion issue tracking it.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4889)